# Why are two of the teeth stuck in space away from my dinosaur?

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, rigify, pose-mode

[image]

I'm sure there are a lot of other issues with my file, because this is basically my first actual animated rig in Blender, but the only issue I'm really concerned with right now is the two bottom teeth that are floating in space.

In edit mode with the mesh selected as well as rest position of the armature, the teeth are in exactly the right place. But when I'm in pose mode, where I've actually animated the dinosaur, two of the teeth are floating in space. Please let me know how to get them to stay in the mouth where they're supposed to be!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the details of your rig, the most significant difference between the two floating teeth and the adjacent teeth or the teeth on the other side is the vertex weight in the `DEF-jaw` vertex group.

[image: DEF-jaw vertex weights]

Assigning full weight to both teeth for this group seems to fix the problem.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much! I didn't realize I had to go to a specific vertex group to weight paint it properly.